Form error when opening Accounting Period on Navision
The following error appears when I try to open a new Accounting Period for 2024.
It has never happened before and we have been using Navision for 20+ years.
"The form can`t recognize control 1"
How do I access the form to know what Control 1 is ?
I checked configuration under General settings in Financial Management, and everything seems to be ok. I have another company set up in the same database and that one gave no issue when opening 2024 in the Accounting Period.

Screenshot or version of Nav would be nice to have.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
